# Conditionally change boolean variable in an imported CSV

Tags: csv, powershell

I am working on a script and I want to compare an array to another array, and change a boolean value (from $false to $true) based on a result.  This works fine on strings using the Replace method, but that doesn't exist for boolean values.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

`$bv` is an array of objects, as follows.

```
ServerName,Domain,Environment,Tier0
ServerA,usa,dev,$false
ServerB,usa,sit,$false
```

I am trying to compare that list to another list of `Tier0` computers (`$t0List`) that looks like this.

```
ServerB
ServerC
ServerD
```

So if there is a match between the ServerName in column 1 of `$bv` and an entry in `$t0List`, then I want to change the `Tier0` column in `$bv` to `$true`.

```
foreach ($b in $bv) {
if ($t0List -contains $b.ServerName) {
    $b.Tier0.Replace($b.Tier0,$true)
    }
}
```

The error I get with the above code is...

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Boolean] does not contain a method named 'Replace'.
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here; we don't know what kind of objects those variables are and it's not completely clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Updated as requested.  I hope that's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use something like replace, just assign the value with `=`:

```
foreach ($b in $bv) {
    if ($t0List -contains $b.ServerName) {
        $b.Tier0 = $true
    }
}
```

Want to simplify it even more? Just assign it the result of your `-contains`:

```
foreach ($b in $bv) {
    $b.Tier0 = $t0List -contains $b.ServerName
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was much easier than it was with strings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

You can flip between `$true` and `$false` just by telling it `-not` to be

`-not $true` brings back `$false`

`-not $false`
brings back 
`$true`

So

```
    foreach ($b in $bv) {
if ($t0List -contains $b.ServerName) {
    $b.Tier0 = -not ($b.Tier0) 
   }
}
```

or

```
    foreach ($b in $bv) {
if ($t0List -contains $b.ServerName) {
    $b.Tier0 = $true
    }
}
```

should work

Comment: I can while reading, but I'd like to store the changed value.  Code and explanation added above to clarify.